# ORA-39083: Object type REF_CONSTRAINT

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, impdp

I am getting Below error while importing dump:

```
Error:
ORA-39083: Object type REF_CONSTRAINT:"SMP54PERFQACM"."ORDR_ITEM_ENTITY_CHG_FK2" failed to create with error:
ORA-02298: cannot validate (SMP54PERFQACM.ORDR_ITEM_ENTITY_CHG_FK2) - parent keys not found
```

Impdp Command:

```
Impdp SMP54PERFQACM/********@orcl12c DUMPFILE=PTSMP54_18Jun2015.dmp REMAP_SCHEMA=PTSMP51QACM:SMP54PERFQACM logfile=imp_SMP54PERFQACM_03aug2015.log directory=BACKUP
```

Can any one please help to resolve this issue?

Thanks
Rahul Joshi

Comment: What are you doing? creating foreign key from parent table to child table or trying to insert in table? When are you getting these errors?

Comment: I am getting this error while importing database.

Comment: The error says that whenever you try to insert the record in child table because of foreign key on child table, value inserted into the table is not found in parent table.

Comment: Yes agree but how to avoid this error in impdp?

Comment: This may helpful. https://community.oracle.com/thread/3542336 Have u referred this post?

Comment: thanks for link.. i read this it means you are saying that i got this error due to domain was up and added some data in database. i am facing some sequence issue for this table only is it because of this only?

Comment: I think you are facing problem of 'HOT PUMP'. https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/Confluence+Upgrade+Fails+with+ORA-02298+Parent+Keys+Not+Found. This will solve the problem related to hot pump. http://snisaac.blogspot.in/2012/08/ora-39083-ora-02298-during-impdp.html

Answer (score 0):

next time try this:

exp user/pass  XXXXXX consistent=y

or

expdp user/pass  XXXXXX flashback_time=systimestamp

take a look to [consistent] and [flashback_time]

good luck.

credits to : https://community.oracle.com/thread/3542336

Answer (score 0):

for me based on the below link the solution was give grant to the user like

```
grant create view, connect, resource to USER_NAME;
```

and then redo the impdp

[oracle community](https://community.oracle.com/thread/843166?tstart=0)